# Password Reset in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean

I am using nodemailer to send in email to myself. I have installed the package but I seem to be getting an error message while running it as "Error not defined"

```
/* Render home page. */
router.get('/reset', function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.render('reset', {
            title: 'Password Reset',
            displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : ''
        });
    }
});
/* Render home page. */
router.post('/reset', function (req, res, next) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'myemail',
            pass: 'email'
        }


    });
    var mailOption = {
        to: 'myemail.com',
        subject: 'Test',
        text: 'Try email' + req.body.name + 'Email' + req.body.email
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOption, function (err, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Send Message: ' + info.response);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `transporter.sendMail`, you use `err` as the argument in your callback function but try to check for `error` instead.